# SQL loop based on table result

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible with one iteration of Loop
to get the following result from table:
Every time to take from everyone cd_number
one number each and its dates.
I tried with a loop but couldn't iterate it the way I need.
SQL question in detail
Is there any other way to retrieve the specific result other than using a loop?

```
table result; 
             cd_number  date_begin  date_end
                 1        03-APR-17   03-JUN-19
                 1        25-FEB-19   03-JUN-20
                 1        13-MAR-20   30-JUN-23
                 2        02-NOV-17   30-APR-18
                 2        25-FEB-19   11-OCT-19
                 3        31-DEC-16   30-OCT-17
                 3        21-OCT-21   16-FEB-22
                 3        19-OCT-22   30-JUN-23

           
             Example table with results
             CREATE TABLE tbl28 (cd_Number int, date_begin date, date_end date );

  insert into tbl28 (cd_Number,date_begin,date_end)
  SELECT 1,  '03-APR-17', '03-JUN-19'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  '25-FEB-19', '03-JUN-19'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  '13-MAR-20', '30-JUN-23'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  '02-NOV-17', '30-APR-18'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  '25-FEB-19', '11-OCT-19'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,  '31-DEC-16', '30-OCT-17'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,  '21-OCT-21', '16-FEB-22'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,  '19-OCT-22', '30-JUN-23'   FROM DUAL;
 
      expected result;
   first iteration    1       03-APR-17   03-JUN-19
                      2       02-NOV-17   30-APR-18
                      3       31-DEC-16   30-OCT-17
   second iteration  
                      1       25-FEB-19   03-JUN-20   
                      2       25-FEB-19   11-OCT-19 
                      3       21-OCT-21   16-FEB-2 2
 and in the third iteration 
                      1       13-MAR-20   30-JUN-23
                      3       19-OCT-22   30-JUN-23
```

Comment: There are cases where you need to loop in sql. But, especially on a platform like Oracle with a mature dialect, they are rare enough that if you ever think "I need a loop here" you can pretty safely assume you are barking up the wrong tree. Both for performance and legibility loops should be an absolute last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to generate the iteration number:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cd_number ORDER BY date_begin) AS iteration,
       cd_number,
       date_begin,
       date_end
FROM   tbl28
ORDER BY iteration, cd_number
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl28 (cd_Number int, date_begin date, date_end date );

insert into tbl28 (cd_Number,date_begin,date_end)
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-04-03', DATE '2019-06-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-02-25', DATE '2019-06-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2020-03-13', DATE '2023-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-02', DATE '2018-04-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2019-02-25', DATE '2019-10-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2016-12-31', DATE '2017-10-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2021-10-21', DATE '2022-02-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2022-10-19', DATE '2023-06-30' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITERATION | CD_NUMBER | DATE_BEGIN | DATE_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2017-04-03 00:00:00 | 2019-06-03 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2017-11-02 00:00:00 | 2018-04-30 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 3 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2017-10-30 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2019-02-25 00:00:00 | 2019-06-03 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 2019-02-25 00:00:00 | 2019-10-11 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021-10-21 00:00:00 | 2022-02-16 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 2020-03-13 00:00:00 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-10-19 00:00:00 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 |

If you only want a specific iteration then enumerate the iterations in a sub-query and then filter in an outer query:

```sql
SELECT cd_number,
       date_begin,
       date_end
FROM   (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cd_number ORDER BY date_begin) AS iteration,
         cd_number,
         date_begin,
         date_end
  FROM   tbl28
  ORDER BY iteration, cd_number
)
WHERE  iteration = 1;
```

Which outputs:

| CD_NUMBER | DATE_BEGIN | DATE_END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-04-03 00:00:00 | 2019-06-03 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2017-11-02 00:00:00 | 2018-04-30 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2017-10-30 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sLSMkbZ8)